# high throughput to mysql, safe inserts?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, performance, mariadb

I receive a lot of data at near concurrent levels from a single websocket connection. The data comes in in json format, with the table name it needs to go into and the data that needs to go into 4 columns (all 4 are int or doubles, to give a sense of the data types & scale).

For example, say I am getting 1000 rows of data per second, needing to go to about 100 different tables (so 10 rows per table per second). I am relatively new to this scale of data in MySQL (specifically MariaDB). Before I embark on this, do I need to worry about writing to the DB this fast? Will there be a backlog/could I lose data that doesn't get inserted if I get another query before the insert is finished? Is there anyway I can tell whether I am missing data?

My plan was to write in python but can adjust to C++ if that will be the issue (only if it will be an issue, not necessarily just to improve performace).

**Full dataflow:**

Websocket Handler:

connect:wss://..../streams?=stream1&..stream100

callback: @process_data(msg)

```
    def process_data(msg):
        #msg exp: {"table":"stream1", "v1":100, "v2":101, "v3":.000005, "v4":.0002} 
        connection.execute("""INSERT INTO {} 
                              VALUES ({}, {}, {}, {})
                           """.format(
                                      msg['table'], 
                                      msg['v1'],
                                      msg['v2'],
                                      msg['v3'],
                                      msg['v4']
                                     )
                           )
```

And I get about 1000 msgs per second.

TL;DR: Will I lose data/get messed up with this setup? It works on a small basis with 2 streams (I think, but I don't know if I am losing data already), but I need to scale it up significantly.

Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Edit: MyMaths != "good"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main overhead is in MySQL, not Python or C++, so don't change app language.

100 `INSERTs`/second is the cutoff I use -- slower than that, and MySQL/MariaDB "just works out of the box".  Faster than that, and you *may* need some tweaking.

Where practical, you get a good boost by inserting multiple rows in a single `INSERT` statement.  I think python has a special call for that.  Inserting 100 rows (into a single table) at a time runs about 10 times as fast as one row per `INSERT`.

SSDs might give you 10x.

There have been benchmarks of 1M/sec -- but that is not for mere mortals on affordable hardware.

There are a few tunables that can changed for InnoDB.  (`innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2`, for example).

As for "missing data" -- that is a question for the other side of your code.  The MySQL side will just get behinder and behinder if it can't keep up.

I assume python has a good library to parse the JSON?

If by "streams", you mean "threads", then you also must have one connection per thread unless you will feed the data back to a single thread to do all the writing.  Either way will work.

Why are there 100 tables?  If all the tables are essentially the same, then it is *probably* a 'bad' schema design.

Build a test framework to stress test your code.  If you get 2000/sec, then the code should be good enough for steadily doing 1000/sec.

If you need to go much beyond 1000/sec, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table

PS:  1000 / 100 is not equal to 100.

Comment: As for 100 tables, that could theoretically be changed, while the data itself is the same, I would need to add group by's for all future transactions on a large database (adding millions of rows a day makes it grow quite large). I just don't have enough experience to optimize the database to a level that I can get subsequent read queries quick enough in the future on a table of that size. Python inherently treats this JSON as a dictionary so it using CPython to accomplish that. As for streams, the websocket I connect to uses the streams for what info to send. e.g. the tag.

Comment: Having 1 huge table versus 100 large tables does not inherently change the performance of a `SELECT` against that much data.  I see your data as being "modestly challenging", not "panic, get out the heavy artillery".  There are many different approaches possible; we need to see what type of data before being more specific about tactics.

Comment: Thanks for your help Mr. James. Much appreciated. You've already given me a lot of help, but as I continue to learn, if there is any resource you would say would be great to learn from in terms of optimizing databases I would love to hear of them.

Comment: @user3672480 - Percona.com has lots of good stuff.  I have http://mysql.rjweb.org/ , especially the cookbook on indexing.  I am available for hire (small gigs only).